# How do I get the time a file was last modified in Python?

Tags: python, file, time

Assuming the file exists (using `os.path.exists(filename)` to first make sure that it does), how do I display the time a file was last modified?  This is on Linux if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[os.stat()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
import os
filename = "/etc/fstab"
statbuf = os.stat(filename)
print("Modification time: {}".format(statbuf.st_mtime))
```

Linux does not record the creation time of a file ([for most fileystems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24441/61642)).

Answer (score 141):

```
>>> import os
>>> f = os.path.getmtime('test1.jpg')
>>> f
1223995325.0
```

since the beginning of (epoch)

Answer (score 57):

New for python 3.4+ (see: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html))

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path('some/path/to/file.ext')
last_modified = path.stat().st_mtime
```